# websites with vulnerabilities INFO

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, exploit-kits

Websites like

1. http://www.cvedetails.com/
2. http://www.securityfocus.com

This websites show information about vulnerabilities and exploits, which other sites are similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for "vulnerability database" before asking this question. Here are some answers:
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search
http://cve.mitre.org/cve/
hxxp://osvdb.org/